# Illegal character in array arg

Tags: packages

I am trying to compile the TeX file of "Relativity: The Special and The General Theory" by Einstein on Gutenberg Project. (The source file: https://github.com/GITenberg/Relativity--The-Special-and-the-General-TheoryA-Popular-Exposition-3rd-ed._36114). But the compiling gives away an error:

> l.5385 \begin{array}{@{}c*{2}{>{\quad}cc}@{}}
>                                                 ?
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

Here is the complete code of the related part:

```
\[
\begin{array}{@{}c*{2}{>{\quad}cc}@{}}
%[** TN: Re-break first column heading to improve overall width]
\ColHead{1}{Number of}{Number of\\ the Star.} &
\ColHead{2}{Observed. Calculated.}{First Co-ordinate. \\[2pt]
$\overbrace{\text{Observed. Calculated.}}$} &
\ColHead{2}{Observed. Calculated.}{Second Co-ordinate. \\[2pt]
$\overbrace{\text{Observed. Calculated.}}$} \\
11 & -0.19 & -0.22 & +0.16 & +0.02 \\
\Z5 & +0.29 & +0.31 & -0.46 & -0.43 \\
\Z4 & +0.11 & +0.10 & +0.83 & +0.74 \\
\Z3 & +0.20 & +0.12 & +1.00 & +0.87 \\
\Z6 & +0.10 & +0.04 & +0.57 & +0.40 \\
10 & -0.08 & +0.09 & +0.35 & +0.32 \\
\Z2 & +0.95 & +0.85 & -0.27 & -0.09
\end{array}
\]
```

I wonder how I can fix this error.

Comment: `\usepackage{array}`

Comment: @Red-Cloud, you are right. After adding `array` package, the error has disappeared.

Comment: @Red-Cloud Do you want to add a solution? Otherwise we could close this as offtopic/solved in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Red-Cloud answered in the comment section, the error arises because of missing `array` package.It is odd that LaTeX doesn't inform you the missing package.